# Please help me with this particular suppression error

Tags: dependencies, suppression

I am trying to suppress certain vulnerabilities via a suppression.xml file. I am following the instructions of the assignment prompt by adding in the complete xml documentation to copy and paste into my suppression file. I am getting an error of "InitializationException: Warn initializing the suppression analyzer: Failed to load suppression.xml, caused by org.owasp.dependencycheck.xml.suppression.SuppressionParseException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Line=14, Column=6: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.." I do not know why this error is happening. I am fairly new to software security as well.

```
<suppressions
    xmlns="https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-suppression.1.3.xsd">
    <suppress>
        <notes><![CDATA[
  file name: spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar
  ]]></notes>
        <packageUrl regex="true">
            ^pkg:maven/org\.springframework\.boot/spring\-boot@.*$
        </packageUrl>
        <cve>CVE-2022-27772</cve>
    </suppress>
</suppressions>
```

```
<suppressions
    xmlns="https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-suppression.1.3.xsd">
    <suppress>
        <notes><![CDATA[
  file name: logback-core-1.2.3.jar
  ]]></notes>
        <packageUrl regex="true">
            ^pkg:maven/ch\.qos\.logback/logback\-core@.*$
        </packageUrl>
        <cve>CVE-2021-42550</cve>
    </suppress>
</suppressions>
```

[suppression.xml code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9NT9.png)

Comment: See the official documentation for an example on how it should look: https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/general/suppression.html

Answer (score 1):

The linked screenshot shows that the top elements are provided twice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<suppressions
    xmlns="https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-suppression.1.3.xsd">
```

You should only declare that once.

Your suppressions look fine. However, all `<supress>` tags should be provided sequentially and within the `<suppression>` tags in the XML file.

Try changing your suppression.xml to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suppressions xmlns="https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-suppression.1.3.xsd">
    <suppress>
        <notes><![CDATA[file name: spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar]]>
       </notes>
        <packageUrl regex="true">
            ^pkg:maven/org\.springframework\.boot/spring\-boot@.*$
        </packageUrl>
        <cve>CVE-2022-27772</cve>
    </suppress>
    <suppress>
        <notes><![CDATA[file name: logback-core-1.2.3.jar]]></notes>
        <packageUrl regex="true">
            ^pkg:maven/ch\.qos\.logback/logback\-core@.*$
        </packageUrl>
        <cve>CVE-2021-42550</cve>
    </suppress>
</suppressions>
```

Also: Where did the `</element>` tag come from? That can be completely removed.